# how to remove and embedded files in ms word using java api

Tags: java

I want to delete embedded files in ms word document using java API and i tried with POI API but it is not working , please suggest best java API.

```
    public static void modifyDocxFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        System.out.println(document.getAllEmbedds().size());
        /*List<PackagePart> embeddedDocs = document.getAllEmbedds();
        if (embeddedDocs != null && !embeddedDocs.isEmpty()) {
            embeddedDocs.remove(0);
        }*/         
        document.getAllEmbedds().remove(0);
        document.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\study\\word\\SampleModified.docx")));


        //System.out.println(document.getAllEmbedds());
        fis.close();
        //fis2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        modifyDocxFile("D:\\study\\word\\Sample.docx");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //readDocFile("C:\\Test.doc");
}
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Please, post a full working example, and tell us what doesn't work, why, what is the expected behaviour and what is happening instead. And if you get errors, post the complete stack trace.

Comment: using poi api i am able to find how many embedded file are in the document  and i tryed to remove first embedded file "embeddedDocs.remove(0);"  but is not throwing any exception and not deleting also

Comment: Post the code [in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40057914/edit), not in comments. However it seems that you are not saving the document.

Comment: added modified code , please suggest

Comment: Have you tried removing the element, and then setting the collection in the document? (it might use defensive copies)

Comment: List<PackagePart> embeddedDocs = document.getAllEmbedds();
document.getAllEmbedds().removeAll(embeddedDocs); // not working